# How to fix a 404 error when the object does exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have a 404 'Not Found' error when I try to edit a mark through my form.
I do not understand where my error comes from because to access this form, I need the brand ID (I can find my ID in my URL though).

Here is the error that my browser returns when I access my modification form (which must pre-fill the fields with the information of the brand concerned (Name and logourl) :

[image: GET http://localhost:8090/api/marque/6]

Here is my project in detail

**FRONT**

1. My Route made with React-Router at `App.js`:

```js
    <Router>

      <Navigation/>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Accueil}/>
        <Route path='/connexion' exact component={Connexion}/>
        <Route path='/inscription' exact component={Inscription}/>
        <Route path='/admin' exact component={Admin}/>
        <Route path='/marque' exact component={Marque}/>
        <Route path='/produit' exact component={Produit}/>
        <Route path='/produit/:id' exact component={Produit}/>
        <Route path='/marque/:id' exact component={Marque}/>
        <Route path='/panier' exact component={Panier}/>
    </Router>
```

2. My Link which sends the ID to access the form  in `adminPage -> marquePage`:

```js
const marqueAffiche = marques.map((marque) => (
                    <TableRow key={marque.id}>
                        <TableCell>{marque.id}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{marque.nom}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>{marque.logourl}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell><Link to={`/marque/${marque.id}`}><IconButton className={classeAdmin.iconUpdate}><UpdateIcon/></IconButton></Link></TableCell>
                        <TableCell><IconButton className={classeAdmin.iconDelete} onClick={() => SupprMarque(marque.id)}><DeleteIcon/></IconButton></TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
        ));
```

3. To get this ID I use Axios via this route in `marque`:

```js
const APIURL = 'http://localhost:8090/api';

export const getMarqueById = (id) => axios.get(`${APIURL}/marque/:id`.replace(':id', id));

export const updateMarque = (id, nom, logourl) => axios.patch(`${APIURL}/marque/${id}`, {
    id: id,
    nom: nom,
    logourl: logourl,
});
```

4. The place where I'm getting an error, in `marquePage`:

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
   
   const { id } = useParams();
   
   useEffect(() => {
        if (id) {
            getMarqueById(id).then(response => {
                // ERROR HAPPEN HERE
                if (response.data){
                    // DON'T GO HERE
                    setMarque({
                        nom: response.data.nom,
                        logourl: response.data.logourl,
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }, [])
```

**BACK**

1. My route and controller for the update :

```js
    // ROUTE (marqueRoute.js)
    app.patch('/api/marque/:id', authenticateJWT,
    body('nom')
        .exists()
        .withMessage('Une marque avec le même nom existe déjà.')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Une marque doit avoir un nom.')
        .isString()
        .withMessage('Le nom de la marque doit être composé uniquement de lettres.'),
    body('logourl')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('La marque doit avoir un logo.'),
    validatorHandler, marqueController.update);
    
    // CONTROLLER (marqueController.js)
    
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    Marques.update({
        nom: req.body.nom,
        logourl: req.body.logourl,
         }, {
             where: {
                 id: req.params.id
             }
         }).then(marque => {
            res.json(marque);
        }).catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
}
```

**NOTE** : For odds reason, my express-validator don't seems to work on my marque (Work fine with everything except this one.)

And I think that is all. If I missed important information, don't hesitate to tell me, I will modify my post accordingly!

**EDIT :**

Indeed, I didn't make a route to get one of my marque.
This is what I've made :

```js
    // Still in the marqueRoute :
    app.get('/api/marque/:id', authenticateJWT, marqueController.get);
    
    // Controller for the GET :
    exports.get = (req, res) => {
    Marques.findByPk(req.params.id).then(marque => {
        res.json(marque);
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
}
```

Don't have an error anymore !

Comment: Where have you defined the get call in the backend? I only see the patch one

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki Edited my post ! I was indeed missing a get call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.patch(...)` means that it will respond to PATCH request only.

However, here is no backend code that responds to GET request.

Therefore, add `app.get(...)`function to handle "getMarqueById" function

Comment: "to POST request" — Not POST! PATCH requests!

Comment: @Promet99 Completely forgot that part ... I was missing my get call.